# How many 'screens' of data could a game store before having to delete some?

Tags: memory

Assuming I was making a Temporal-esque time travel game, and wanted a to save the current state of the screen (location of player and enemies, whether or not destructible objects are destroyed, et cetera) every second to an array, how much data would I be able to store on this array before the game would start to lag considerably and I would have to either delete the array or save it to a file out of the game (ie: a .bin).

On a similar note, is it faster to constantly save every screen to a .bin, or to only do this when it is necessary (start saving when the array is halfway 'full', for example).

And I know that the computer it is being run on matters, but assume it is being run on a reasonably modern computer (not old, but not a nasa supercompeter either), particularily because I have no way of telling exactly what the people who play the game will be using.

Comment: I don't know whether to put this in the question, but this is mostly hypothetical.  I might do something like this eventually, but for the most part I'm asking this out of curiosity.

Comment: @womp +1 for this wink that made me smile!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you use the data afterwards, you could consider storing the changes between states instead of the actual states.

You should use a buffer to reduce the number of I/O-operations. Put data in main memory and write a larger amount of data to disk when needed.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the amount of objects you needs to save and how much memory is taken up by each object.

Hypothetically, let's take a vastly oversimplified and naive example, and say that your game contains an average of 40 objects, each of which has 20 properties that take up two bytes of storage.  That's 1600 bytes per second, if you're saving each second.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is impossible to give you an answer that will definitely work for your scenario. You'll need to try a few things.

Assuming you are loading large images, sounds, or graphics from disk it may not be good to write to disk with high frequency due to contention. I say *may* because it really depends on th computer and everything that is going on. So how do you deal with this issue? One way is to run a background thread that watches a queue for items that need to be written to disk. The thread can monitor the queue for a certain number of items before writing to disk. The alternative is to wait for certain other events to happen in the game where I/O is happening and save it then. You may need to analyse the size of events that you are saving and try different options.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to get an estimate as to how much data is saved per screen, then decide how much of someone's memory you want to use, and then just divide, as you will have huge variances. I am using a 64 bit OS so how much you can store on my machine is different than on a 32-bit machine.

You may want to decide what is actually needed. For example, if you just save the properties of each object into a json array you may save yourself some space, but you want to limit how much you write to a disk, as that will need to be done on a separate thread that only writes to this file, so that you don't have two threads trying to access the same resource, queue up the writes.

Saving the music, for example, may not be useful, as that will change anyway, I expect.

Be very judicious about what you will save, try it and see if you are saving enough.